# C# Dictionary recursion

Tags: c#, dictionary, recursion, indexing, self-contained

I'm searching for a construct in c# where Dictionaries contain Dictionaries to count `n`. I want to put a list of Dictionaries into and it builds some kind of index.

I want to call it like `dic[key][key2][key3]` where the value is object or a Dictionary or a Dictionary containing more Dictionaries.

I think elastic can provide something like that but our solution is a standalone client application.

Comment: `Dictionaries contain Dictionaries to count n` -- I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: You can easily create nested dictonaries, but if you don't know the nesting level or it isn't fixed, a generic (type safe) `Dictionary` may not be your best choice. For example, `Dictionary<TKey, Dictionary<TKey, Dictionary<TKey, object>>>`.

Comment: @NetMage I thougth about that but yes I don't know the recursion level. May be MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, MyDictionary> but where to stop?

Comment: Instead of trying to fit your data into predetermined structure you will be better off describing your data and [determining which data structure fits it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: could an alternative solution be using a regular, _flat_ `Dictionary<string[],object>`? that way, you can still quite easily navigate from `["key","key2"]` to `["key","key2","key3"]` (alternatively: concatting the strings with a separator character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries can be nested like this:

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

To initialise a nested dictionary:

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>
        {
            { "a1", new Dictionary<string, int> { { "b1a", 1 }, { "b1b", 2 } } },
            { "a2", new Dictionary<string, int> { { "b2a", 3 }, { "b2b", 4 } } }
        };
```

You then index into the dictionary like this:

```
        int x = dictionary["a1"]["b1a"];
        Assert.AreEqual(1, x);
```

EDIT: to have an arbitrary depth, you need to create your own type that has built-in nesting, e.g.,

```
    class Node
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, Node> Children { get; set; }

        // The indexer indexes into the child dictionary.
        public Node this[string key] => Children[key];
    }
```

Normally I would define Children as a List, but you want dictionaries.

Sample usage:

```
        var node = new Node
        {
            Children = new Dictionary<string, Node>
            {
                { "a1", new Node
                    {
                        Children = new Dictionary<string, Node>
                        {
                            { "b1a", new Node { Value = 1 } },
                            { "b1b", new Node { Value = 2 } }
                        }
                    }
                },
                { "a2", new Node
                    {
                        Children = new Dictionary<string, Node>
                        {
                            { "b2a", new Node { Value = 3 } },
                            { "b2b", new Node { Value = 4 } }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        int y = node["a1"]["b1a"].Value;
        Assert.AreEqual(1, y);
```

This can go as deep as you like--just stick another Dictionary into the Children property of a leaf node.

Comment: Yes thanks. But how to build It if I don't know the recursion level?

Comment: Now you have clarified you need an arbritary depth then dictionaries are not the best solution.